# What mean coefficients in autoregressive model and how calculate them?

Tags: regression, time-series, autoregressive

What mean coefficients in autoregressive model and how calculate them ?

```
yt=c+ϕ1yt−1+ϕ2yt−2+⋯+ϕpyt−p+et,
ϕ1, ϕ2 ...
```

This coefficients are "fourier transform"?
Can someone provide simple example or give link  ? 
but not in excel or R.. no, simple calculation on paper by the hand, because each of resources show almost final result.

Regards

Comment: They tell you how past values of $y_t$ affect current ones. I do not see what you mean by "calculate them" - it's a model, so the coefficients are just "there" so to speak.

Comment: Ok, if coefficients just "there" ... what value will be for ϕ1 - ? ϕ2 - ? or for ϕ13 - ?

Comment: We don't know. We estimate these parameters, like we estimate other unknown quantities, too.

Comment: How We estimate these parameters?

Comment: by OLS, regressing $y_t$ on $y_{t-1}$ etc, for example

Comment: Sorry, maybe last one: dickey fuller test also use same coefficients (OLS) for checking stationarity ? (p=1)

Comment: yes, it does so